# Laravel Composer update doesn't pass

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, maatwebsite-excel

I use **Laravel 5.0** and I need to use [maatwebsite/excel](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/getting-started#installation) for my job but after, I update Composer I have the following error:

> ```
>  Problem 1
>     - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.0.35
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.35
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.34
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.33
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.32
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.31
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework 5.0.30
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.29
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.28
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.27
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.26
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.25
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.24
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.23
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.22
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.21
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.20
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.19
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.18
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.17
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.16
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.15
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.14
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.13
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.12
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.11
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.10
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.9
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.8
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.7
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.6
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.5
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.4
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.3
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.2
>     - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.0.1
>     - laravelcollective/html v5.2 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
>     - laravelcollective/html v5.2.1 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
>     - laravelcollective/html v5.2.2 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
>     - laravelcollective/html v5.2.3 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
>     - laravelcollective/html v5.2.4 requires illuminate/view 5.2.* -> satisfiable by illuminate/view[v5.2.0, v5.2.19, v5.2.21, v5.2.24, v5.2.25, v5.2.26, v5.2.27, v5.2.28, v5.2.31, v5.2.6, v5.2.7].
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.19|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.21|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.24|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.25|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.26|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.27|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.28|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.31|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.6|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - don't install illuminate/view v5.2.7|don't install laravel/framework v5.0.0
>     - Installation request for laravel/framework 5.0.* -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[5.0.30, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.10, v5.0.11, v5.0.12, v5.0.13, v5.0.14, v5.0.15, v5.0.16, v5.0.17, v5.0.18, v5.0.19, v5.0.2, v5.0.20, v5.0.21, v5.0.22, v5.0.23, v5.0.24, v5.0.25, v5.0.26, v5.0.27, v5.0.28, v5.0.29, v5.0.3, v5.0.31, v5.0.32, v5.0.33, v5.0.34, v5.0.35, v5.0.4, v5.0.5, v5.0.6, v5.0.7, v5.0.8, v5.0.9].
>     - Installation request for laravelcollective/html 5.2.* -> satisfiable by laravelcollective/html[v5.2, v5.2.1, v5.2.2, v5.2.3, v5.2.4].
> ```

My `composer.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {

        "laravel/framework": "5.0.*",
        "illuminate/html": "5.*",
        "laravelcollective/html": "5.2.*",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

What should I do with my Laravel?

Comment: sounds like the version of PHP you are running does not meet the requirements of Laravel 5. Min version is "php": ">=5.5.9". you can check your's by doing `php -v`

Comment: Can you show us your `composer.json` file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/y8XSGwSL

Comment: I would try removing your composer.lock file and redoing an install

Comment: What's in your database folder? i noticed composer has a classmap to it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use laravelcollective/html in Version 5.2.* together with Laravel 5.0.* because the former requires the latter to be at least Laravel 5.2.*.

It has nothing to do with maatwebsite/excel being incompatible.